# Is this Evaluation of definite Integral correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

To Evaluate $$I=\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{dx}{x^2+x+1+\sqrt{x^4+3x^2+1}}$$

I rationalized the denominator getting as

$$I=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{x^2+x+1-\sqrt{x^4+3x^2+1}}{2x(x^2+1)}$$ $\implies$

$$I=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{2x}+\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{2(x^2+1)}+\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{x^4+3x^2+1}\:dx}{2x(x^2+1)}$$

First and Third integrals are zero as the Integrands are odd functions and hence

$$I=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{2(x^2+1)}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: I think we Need a numerical method here!

Comment: Looks fine using a numerical approach:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kucxkwvje6

Comment: Why? What's the motivation of this question?

Comment: We get $$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{x^2+x+1+\sqrt{x^4+3x^2+1}}\approx 0.785398$$

Comment: I think your third integral should have a negative in front.

Comment: The first and third integrals diverge.

Comment: See https://www.integral-calculator.com/

Answer (score 1):

> *Is this Evaluation of definite Integral correct?*

No.

Your final result is right, but we have
$$
\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{x}\ne0,\qquad \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{x^4+3x^2+1}\:dx}{x(x^2+1)}\ne0, \tag1
$$ **each integral being divergent**, it is the difference of the preceding integrals which vanishes, that is 
$$
\int_{-1}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\sqrt{x^4+3x^2+1}\:dx}{x(x^2+1)}\right)dx=0. \tag2
$$To prove $(2)$, one may observe the integrand is an odd function over $[-1,1]$ **and** one may observe the integral is **convergent**, since the singularity of the integrand as $x \to 0$ is removable,
$$
\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\sqrt{x^4+3x^2+1}\:dx}{x(x^2+1)}\right) \sim -\frac x2,
$$ the function being continuous elsewhere.